# How to emit JSON errors from JSON handlers without redefining `errorHandler` for the whole app?

Tags: json, haskell, yesod

I'm trying to build a site with a JSON-service inside it. So I want to have a different error handling for different handlers. For example, `notFound` must return HTML "Not found" in `Handler Html` and JSON value `{"error": "not found"}` in `Handler Value`. How can I achieve it?

Even when I'm using my own `notFoundJson`, Yesod's `get404` doesn't and returns HTML even inside `Handler Value`.

1. Should I get return type of a handler inside `errorHandler`?
2. Should I make `/api` a subsite and override `errorHandler` for it?
3. Should I make another yesod, with its own specific `errorHandler`, and connect it to the main yesod as a subsite?

Comment: It is acceptable to answer your own question.  It prevents this question from showing up as "unanswered", too.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. I did it, but somebody deleted it, and a few users noticed that I should use "edit" to add information. Do you consider it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple solution:** You haven't to do anything. It is a client's concern.

According to `defaultErrorHandler` implementation, the proper way to receive JSON error for client seems to be to provide HTTP header `Accept: application/json` or query parameter `?_accept=application/json` in request.

`defaultErrorHandler` itself provides two representations: one for `text/html` client and one for `application/json` client. Default is the former.

**More generic solution:** Add a [WAI middleware](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/web-application-interface) that appends HTTP header `Accept: application/json` or query parameter `?_accept=application/json` for specific urls.

Comment: how would you add the WAI middleware just for `api/*` routes?

Comment: @amitaibu, you can't, but you can look at URL inside the middleware and append the only if URL starts with `/api`.